# How can I find all files in the current directory with matching text (excluding parent and recursive directories)?

Tags: bash, shell, grep

I want to find:

- all the files in the current directory containing text `search-term`
- including hidden and non-hidden files
- without `SomeDir is a directory` messages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

`grep --directories=skip 'search-term' * .*`

Notes:

`--directories=skip` will skip all directories (including the parent directory)

`* .*` will search all files (hidden and non-hidden)